# Difference between standard and extended Steinhart-Hart equation

Tags: thermistor

I looked up the data table for a thermistor I purchased and noticed it uses an 'extended' Steinhart-Hart equation. I'd like to understand the difference between these equations, such as how the D coefficient is acquired, whether more coefficients add accuracy, and so on.

The standard Steinhart-Hart equation I had seen is:

[image: standard Steinhart-Hart eqn]

On the [thermistor data sheet](http://www.vishay.com/docs/29049/ntcle100.pdf), page 4 includes the 'extended' Steinhart-Hart equation:

[image: extended Steinhart-Hart equation]

Is the inclusion of a D coefficient here simply an instance of resistance data having been measured for a third temperature? Does the inclusion of an additional coefficient relate in some way to the material properties of the thermistor? Or did the manufacturer simply choose to include it for further accuracy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the **general form** of the Steinhart-Hart equation is an **infinite sum** (see German Wikipedia article of [Steinhart-Hart equation](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhart-Hart-Gleichung)):

\$\frac{1}{T} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k \ln^k \frac{R}{R_{ref}} \$

In most practical cases it is enough to approximate by using only 3 of the first 4 coefficients \$c_0, c_1, c_3\$ (in your case called \$A, B, C\$) and throw away the rest (as \$c_2\$ often is small enough to neglect and the terms with higher powers of \$\ln \frac{R}{R_{ref}}\$ become less and less significant).

In your case, obviously, in the "extended" equation just some extra effort was taken to also use coefficient \$c_2\$ in order to get a better approximation.

Probably the coefficients are obtained not only by measuing at a 4th temperature but by doing many (>4) measurements at many temperatures in the interesting range and doing least-square [curve fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting) using a 4th order polynomial as model function.

Comment: I think you are wrong... Where did you get the R_ref?

Answer (score 4):

The most **general** form of the Steinhart-Hart equation is given by
$$ \frac {1}{T} = A + B\ln(R) + C(\ln R)^2 + D(\ln R)^3 $$

In the **standard** Steinhart-Hart equation the C parameter is set to zero, because it is typically much smaller than the other coefficients.  However, some manufacturers use all 4 coefficients.

Because A, B, C and D are "arbitrarily" chosen from the alphabet, the **standard** Steinhart-Hart equation is written as
$$ \frac {1}{T} = A + B\ln(R) + \color{red}C(\ln R)^3 $$
instead of
$$ \frac {1}{T} = A + B\ln(R) + \color{red}{D}(\ln R)^3 $$